# how to call a function pointer via boost thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

`class A 
    {
    public:
        int xx(int size)
        {
        }
    public:
        int xx(int size)
        {
        }
        int yy(int size)
         {
        }
    };
    int main()
     {
        typedef int (A::*functions)(int);
        std::vector<functions> methods = 
        {
            &A::xx,
            &A::yy
        };
        A aa;
        boost::thread_group thgrp;
        for (typename std::vector<functions>::iterator itr=methods.begin();itr!=methods.end();++itr)
        {
            functions z=*itr;
            boost::thread *t=new boost::thread(z,aa,10);
            thgrp.add_thread(t);
        }
        thgrp.join_all();
        return 0;
    }`

I'm getting an error "no matching function for call to 'get_pointer'".
I want to call the methods from the vector of my predefined type using boost threads.

Please help me to solve this!

Comment: Perhaps send `&aa` ?

Comment: ...And that isn't valid C++ code. You have two members for class `A` that have identical names (`xx`) and signatures (`int`). And neither `xx` nor `yy` return anything, but are declared to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!!!

I found the mistake done by me! this code is working properly!
i called boost::thread with the object "methods" instead of the object to the class "aa".